# Audio tag security in html5

Tags: html, security, audio

**Long version:**

I use html5 audio tag to play mp3 files on my website. With Flash I can stream mp3's and secure it for 95%.

With html5 it is easy to find out the mp3 location and just download it from there. Even if I secure it with unique hashes it is not hard to inspect the network tab in chrome and see the mp3 url with hashes.

I was wondering if there are other ways to secure the mp3 from being ripped and if it is worth the time. For example [bandcamp](http://www.bandcamp.com/) does generate unique hashes but it is still very easy to download the mp3. For youtube you got download websites that can proces the flv stream and rip the audio and save it for the user as mp3 format.

The first layer of security I can think of is change the extension of mp3 files to .txt or another common format.

95% of the users don't spot the extension because it is hidden by default on windows and apple. This will prevent the first 95% of the users to spot and play the mp3 file.

**Short Version**

Any suggestions to prevent users from stealing mp3 files while using html5 audio tag.

Comment: Is it your music?  Why not just stream a low quality copy and use unique hashes to semi protect it.

Comment: Or whisper your domain name in the middle of the mp3 every now and then.

Comment: Both good options to consider. Different artists gave me the rights to play the audio on the website.

Comment: In that case I think your better off with low quality streams and links to buy the full quality version.

Comment: One possible way to hide it would be to only serve the mp3s as dataURI's eg song.mp3.txt, very easy to decode by extracting the datauri (content) and pasting it directly into the browser window, but most users would not be aware of how to do this. Looking in the 'network' tab, you will not see a transfer of any mp3s only a data/.... A downside to this method however, is you will either have to convert all your mp3s to dataURI's manually or write a datauri parser on your server.

Comment: Things have progress - check my answer at the bottom there

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Kind of.**

Grooveshark send a POST request to a server-side script for the MP3 that is being streamed which makes it very difficult to just access and spoof without dynamically creating a POST request yourself - especially seeing as you would have to then attempt to store the audio file that is collected. But you can use the new AudioContext to help solve this for most modern platforms...

I used a great example from HTML5Rocks.com to alter the headers used as follows:

```
var dogBarkingBuffer = null;
// Fix up prefixing
window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
var context = new AudioContext();

function loadDogSound(url) {
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('POST', url, true);
  request.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

  // Decode asynchronously
  request.onload = function() {
    context.decodeAudioData(request.response, function(buffer) {
      dogBarkingBuffer = buffer;
    }, onError);
  }
  //this is the encryption key
  request.send("key=98753897358975387943");
}
```

[Related](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro/)

As you can see I am also sending a key value which could possibly be part of a public/private pair too. This should put anyone off attempting to intervene - other than simply recording the MP3 as it's playing, of course, but what could possibly stop that in any environment inside or out of a computer?

Comment: Nice snippet. This seems pretty solid and will certainly prevent 99% of the common users to steal mp3's

Comment: Thanks - it's in my interest to use this pretty soon too so I'm just glad I came across this thread as it helped me to work this problem out. Props go to grooveshark and Alex Reidy's pointer.

Comment: Sorry, but what does prevent me to see the resource in my chrome console and have access to it ?

Comment: @Snick You could send a unique stream each time and append it to the audio stream periodically. Also, having a public encryption key means you can only do it the once for one periodic handshake and not share the link. Even more so, you could do a per-part encryption key. There are so many levels to the imagination that you could do with this, so it's more a high level deterrent.

Comment: Ahh, I see, that would request on the server side an active process to handle the per part encryption and stream concatenation, right? I guess it wouldn't work with cdn'ed content.

Comment: Correct - so I would say that it would be inefficient unless you had some special behaviour on the CDN. It's all food for thought, really... I can't think of a decent scenario for this other than having a public/private key on a single file that gets reprocessed on a semi-regular basis, i.e. daily. Doing that with a CDN sounds like a lot of bandwidth usage.

Comment: But even so, you could do it on a weekly basis and justify that against the large amount of download bandwidth being used, and if you had that many files against that usage then I'm sure it's all workable.

Answer (score 8):

**Short Answer**

No.

Renaming the audio file to .txt is not going to do anything to help the security of your mp3 audio file. If anything, it is going to cause you even more issues, because now, your mp3 audio file is going to be sent with the incorrect MIME type, which may cause issues with the browser's built in audio player.

The best suggestions that I can provide you is:

1. Make sure that your checking the REFERER http header, make sure that it is coming from the page that has the mp3 player on it.
2. Protect the mp3 file with a unique hash.
3. Don't allow the same hash to be downloaded twice*

*Note that even doing this could cause issues, for example, what happens if the user reopens a tab from cache, plays the file again, and the mp3 file is not cached?

And finally, at the end even after your mp3 file is the most protected mp3 file in the history of IIS and Apache -- what is stopping me from just opening up Adobe Audition, and recordinging the audio stream?

Although you are correct about Bandcamp's MP3 audio stream, the mp3 is not as high quality then just a normal download after purchasing an album.

The fact that even Google does not really have any decent protections on it's video streams should say something. A company that generates billions of dollars from video views on YouTube can't even make (or better put -- has not bothered to put in place) any viable methods for protecting their videos.

Comment: True, renaming to txt is a bad practice and will probally run into more issues that solve any.

Comment: Good answer, but things have progressed a tad thankfully - please check out my answer below

Answer (score 0):

You could make the MP3s themselves unattractive. Some ideas:

- Don't include album art, album info, etc. in your files (id3 tags). Even better, fill out all id3 tag fields with something like "This file is from myMusicSite.com".
- Split your files into several smaller pieces, and then play them in sequence in the browser. Having to download all the individual pieces will make your files much less attractive. You may have problems with gapless playback, not sure how well that's supported though.
- Encode and play them as a video, maybe with your logo or something as the video stream. The resulting files won't be much larger, esp. if you use a static image. This will mean that users can't play your files on mp3 players, phones, etc. easily.
- Whisper your domain name or website name in the recordings a few times, as mentioned in the comments.